# what does "until it's realized value is required" in deferred execution means?

Tags: c#, deferred-execution

I'm just wondering. And been looking in Deferred Execution. It says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx that `Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is delayed until its realized value is actually required.`

What does "Until its realized value is actually required" means? Are there methods or property for the value to be realized? Just like the `.ToList()`

Hope you get what I'm pointing on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deferred execution** is used to mean that no database query will be fired until an IQueryable is iterated.

Let say.

```
    var employees = db.Employees.Where(x=>x.FirstName == "Krish"); //No query issued
var count = employees.Count(); // now a query is issued
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This clarifies my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of the query is delayed until the query is actually enumerated.  A `foreach` loop or calling `.ToList()` will force the query to be executed.

Comment: I see. Much clearer now. But are there other methods besides `.ToList()`?

Comment: `First()`, `Count()`, etc. -- anything which results in a value from the sequence.

Comment: Any of the Linq Methods that return a calculated value will execute the query as well, such as `Count()`, `Sum()`, `Min()` or `Max()`

Comment: Precisely, every query with immediate execution will trigger deferred execution. Typically methods not returning `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: This really helps me understanding deferred execution.